# Rewriting a Variable with BufferedReader

Tags: java

im kinda new in this i was wondering if i can modify a variable that is already defined in a BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
System.out.println("insert a number: ");   
int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  
if (i == 3)
{  
  System.out.println("Error, please type the number again: ");  
  int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}
```

I want to let the user input a new value but i dont know how.

Comment: Make a `loop` and break if `i==-1`for example.

Comment: instead `readLine()` use `br.readLine()`.

Comment: @Satya yeah, i forgot to put it in the code above

Comment: There is no such thing as 'a variable that is already defined in a BufferedReader.` What are you really asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a while loop that checks for whatever variable you are looking for. So something like:

```
while(i == 3){
  System.out.println("Error, please type the number again: ");  
  i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}
```